# AppleScript - Syntax Error trying to extract text

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to create a basic script that extracts some text from a webpage, but when I save I'm getting a Syntax error that I don't understand...

... please see **screenshot.**

The second Set (Role1Result) is working fine.

I'm a bit of a newbie at this, so any help really appreciated.

Here's the relevant bit of code pasted:

```
    set tid to AppleScript's text item delimiters -- save them for later.
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to startText -- find the first one.
    set liste to text items of SearchText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to endText -- find the end one.
    set extracts to {}
    repeat with subText in liste
        if subText contains endText then
            copy text item 1 of subText to end of extracts
        end if
    end repeat
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tid -- back to original values.
    return extracts
end extractText



--- roles ---

set role0Result to extractText(input0, "      <dd class="result-lockup__highlight-keyword">
          <span data-anonymize="job-title" class="t-14 t-bold">", "</span>
            <span>
    at
    ")

set role1Result to extractText(input1, "      <dd class=\"result-lockup__highlight-keyword\">
          <span class=\"t-14 t-bold\">", "</span>
            <span>
")
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You'll need to escape some of the quotes - most likely those surrounding job-title and result-lockup...   Curiously, you seem to have done this in the next block of text.

Comment: Ah amazing, thank you! So simple ;)

Answer (score 0):

Within a string literal you have to escape all occurrences of double quotes with a backslash

```
set role0Result to extractText(input0, "      <dd class=\"result-lockup__highlight-keyword\">
      <span data-anonymize=\"job-title\" class=\"t-14 t-bold\">", "</span>
        <span>
at
")
```